# How to make it such that if there are errors in the form, all the data I have keyed into the field remains and only the error pops out

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

How to make it such that if there are errors in the form, all the data I have keyed into the field remains and the error shows for me to edit what I need to edit.

Because it is very user-unfriendly if people press submit, and everything they have previously typed has to be retyped again due to an error that caused them to need to submit the form again.

just like when we post a stackoverflow question, if there are errors in our question eg time limit, whatever we have typed previously remains

Let me know if you require more code.

html

```
   <form class="create-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="id_title">Title</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" id="id_title" placeholder="Title" required autofocus>
   </div>
   <button class="submit-button btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>

  </form>

  {% if form.errors %}
  {% for field in form %}
      {% for error in field.errors %}
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
              <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
          </div>
      {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

views.py

```
def create_blog_view(request):
    context = {}
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateBlogPostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)    
        if form.is_valid():
            obj.save()
            return redirect('HomeFeed:main')
        else:
            context['form'] = form
    return render(request, "HomeFeed/create_blog.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering the fields manually by writing the tags. When you render using the form instance Django automatically sets the value attributes with the previous values. You can use `{{ form.as_table }}`, `{{ form.as_p }}`, `{{ form.as_ul }}`. You can also render fields individually using `{{ form.title }}` where `title` is the field name.

Comment: yep i understand that. if based on my situation I prefer to rendering the fields manually by writing the tags, could you suggest how I can ensure it automatically sets the value attributes with the previous values

Comment: @hoehoehoe you can look into using [django-widget-tweaks](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks), quite a good solution to customize the rendering of fields in Django. (Most likely you want to write the css classes etc. in the template which can be easily done using widget-tweaks)

Comment: @hoehoehoe also `{{ form.title.value }}` would give you the fields value. [Looping over the form’s fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields)